# Is there a way to set a Content-Security-Policy header to say don't run javascript from any URL that has a hostname

Tags: http-headers, content-security-policy

Our web application serves pages and pages of javascript files among other things. We are going through a security scanner and it recommended a Content-Security-Policy header, which isn't a bad thing. But there's an ugly wrinkle. We serve all of our javascript via '/js/...' links and are behind a reverse-proxy server and can be loaded via multiple paths. The consequence of all that is we don't actually know our own URL on the server side.

So I could place the header only if I can say no host names allowed.

If I really needed a hostname I could probably do something like this, but I understand that it's verboten.

```
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT>
document.write('<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Security-Policy" ...>');
</SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT SRC="/js/public/require.js"></SCRIPT>
...
```

There's a few places where we fetch data (not javascript) from outside paths; I suppose I'll just have to manually add the URLs to the list on those pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The consequence of all that is we don't actually know our own URL on the server side.

**Opt 1.** URL means:

```
[scheme://] [host] [:port] [/path]
```

even if you use relative URLs like `<SCRIPT SRC="/js/public/require.js"></SCRIPT>`, browsers follow Same Origin Policy and use `[scheme://] [host] [:port]` form the parent window.
Hence you anyway have a `host` (domain name). Even if you use IP address as `host`, this IP become a host name (but you loose ability of `https:`).
Real `host` always presents, and to know `path` on the server is not mandatory for CSP.

Therefore you can use `script-src 'self'` to denote own host name through which web app operates. Alternatively you can use `script-src your_domain.com` or even `script-src your_domain.com/js/` if you wish to allow scripts from `/js/` folder only.

**Opt 2.** Use the `'nonce-value'`:

Publish the CSP with `script-src 'nonce-base64value';` and use base64value as **nonce=** attribute value in scripts:

`<SCRIPT SRC="/js/public/require.js" nonce="base64value"></SCRIPT>`

`<SCRIPT nonce="base64value">alert('Hello');</SCRIPT>`

Comment: Interesting. Searching for content-security-provider script-src self found a much better document page than I was working on. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src

Comment: “or even `script-src your_domain.com/js/` if you wish to allow scripts from `/js/` folder only.” I don’t believe that’s correct. CSP works on schemes and domains but not paths.

Comment: CSP2 and CSP3 spec allows to use [path-part](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#match-paths). Pls see the [test of using path-part](https://csplite.com/csp/test120/) in the rules. Also filenames is supported too.