# how to configure content security policy header in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, apache2, codeigniter-3, content-security-policy

Please anyone provide solution how do I set the content security policy header in code igniter 3?
I tried a lot but nothing happen.

thanks

I am doing like this

```
$this->output->set_header('Content-Security-Policy', "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inine';");
```

in _construct function in controller but it doesn't work.

Comment: what are you using this for? like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65963216/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-content-security-policy-header-to-say-dont-run-javascri

Comment: did you observe and follow this: [set_output()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/output.html?highlight=set_header#CI_Output::set_output)? *Important: If you do set your output manually, it must be the last thing done in the function you call it from. For example, if you build a page in one of your controller methods, don’t set the output until the end.* Having this in a constructor, doesn't sound to me last output...